How to get only one row mysql table displayed using PHP
How to get only one row  I Currently have this code that displays all entries rows from a mysql table and displays them on a api not get row how to data php  image first row id how to get image;
public function getHome1()
{
    include "../includes/config.php";
    $setting_qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_settings where id = '1'";
    $setting_result = mysqli_query($connect, $setting_qry);
    $settings_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($setting_result);
    $api_key = $settings_row['api_key'];
    $comment_approval = $settings_row['comment_approval'];

    if (isset($_GET['api_key'])) {
        $access_key_received = $_GET['api_key'];

        if ($access_key_received == $api_key) {
            $limit = 10;

            if ($this->get_request_method() != "GET") $this->response('', 406);

            $query_post1 = "SELECT DISTINCT n.recipe_id, n.recipe_title, n.cat_id, n.recipe_time,n.price,n.discountprice, n.recipe_image, n.recipe_description, n.video_url, n.video_id, n.content_type, n.featured, n.tags, n.total_views, COUNT(DISTINCT r.comment_id) as comments_count, c.category_name 
            FROM tbl_recipes1 n 
            LEFT JOIN tbl_category1 c ON n.cat_id = c.cid
            LEFT JOIN tbl_comments1 r ON n.recipe_id  = r.recipe_id
            WHERE c.cid = '$row[1]' AND n.content_type = 'Post' 
            GROUP BY n.recipe_id
            ORDER BY n.recipe_id DESC LIMIT $limit ";

            $post1 = $this->get_list_result($query_post1);

            $respon = array('status' => 'ok', 'featured' => $featured, 'category' => $category, 'recent' => $recent, 'post1' => $post1, 'videos' => $videos);
            $this->response($this->json($respon), 200);

        } else {
            $respon = array('status' => 'failed', 'message' => 'Oops, API Key is Incorrect!');
            $this->response($this->json($respon), 404);
        }
    } else {
        $respon = array('status' => 'failed', 'message' => 'Forbidden, API Key is Required!');
        $this->response($this->json($respon), 404);
    }
}


Use LIMIT 1 instead of LIMIT 10.
